# access to gnome configuration information using python

Tags: python, gnome

Is there a standard way of accessing Gnome configuration information (i.e. `~/.gconf`) using Python?

**Updated**: please provide a short example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python GConf, also check out packages like **python-gconf** and/or **gnome-python-gconf** in your distros package repo:

> /usr/share/doc/python-gconf/examples/

Or **browse the svn** at http://svn.gnome.org/viewvc/gnome-python/trunk/examples/gconf/ for the examples.

On Fedora12 (my distro) it is called [gnome-python2-gconf-2.28.0-1.fc12.x86_64.rpm](http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/fedora/linux/releases/12/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/gnome-python2-gconf-2.28.0-1.fc12.x86_64.rpm), but it may be in a generic gnome-python2 package.

An example of GConf key editing (background wallpaper) in Python:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import gtk
import gtk.glade
import gconf

class GConfExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = gconf.client_get_default()

    def get_key(self, key):
        return client.get_string(key)

    def set_key(self, key, val):
        client.set_string(key, str(val))
```

Found http://therning.org/magnus/archives/57 , and I trimmed out the GTK stuff. Of course, this would make some good **getitem** and **setitem** usage to map for example:

```
mygconf['/path/to/key'];
```

Also some good information [here](http://mikedesjardins.us/wordpress/category/gconf/) about using the API. Of course, my example is poor, but illustrates the simplicity of the API. Here are more methods:

```
foo = self.gconf_client.get_string("/path/to/my/config/data/foo")
bar = self.gconf_client.get_int("/path/to/my/config/data/bar")
baz = self.gconf_client.get_bool("/path/to/my/config/data/baz")
```

And each `get_*` has an equivalent setter `set_*` in most cases.

Comment: old answer, links you gave don't work and the examples are no longer kept in /usr/share/doc/python/conf  at least not on ubuntu.